# Fix Snapping Rotation in Edit Mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, snapping

**I'm using Blender's snapping feature to add hex bolts to an object, in edit mode.**

I've turned on snapping, Snap with Center, Snap To Face, and Align Rotation to Target. But for some reason the bolts are snapping at odd angles. How can I fix this? Thanks!

[image]

**Here is the Blender file:**

[image]

Comment: Hello are you sure that the Z axis of the bolt is pointing upwards?

Comment: can u pls provide a blend file so we can see all of your settings? thxx

Comment: I must be missing something .. in Edit Mode the bolt-meshes don't have a Z axis to align to? So do it in Object Mode? You can always join the dupes later...  if they're Alt D instances, you can use Shift L to select them all for joining.

Comment: @Chris Blender file has been uploaded. Thanks!

Comment: @RobinBetts Yeah maybe doing it in object mode would just be better. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it's doable in Edit mode, but you can separate the bolt as another object, put the origin at its bottom, exactly like Alex shows, you'll join the bolt afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to fix the issue seems to be to separate the bolts into there own object. Then in object mode, place the bolts on the mesh. Once you are finished placing the bolts, select all the bolt objects, then the main object, and press Control J, to join them together into the same object.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are in face selection mode so that it aligns according to the face normal

[image]

Then press G, then B to select the snap base

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. when I press G, and then B, it does fix the rotation, but then the bolt doesn't move with the mouse. I will edit the post and upload the Blender file so that you can take a look.

Comment: Hi, Alex.. interesting :) How do you handle duplicates?  Can you get consistency? So far, this seems to work for me only if the nut is created at the origin of the main mesh, and duplicated from there. So far, for me, that behaviour seems lucky, and the orientation seems generally 'undefined' in Edit Mode, unless.. you've found a way to control it?

Comment: @RyanKingArt Not sure why it does this, when I do the steps with your file the bolt does move

Comment: @RobinBetts Doing it in edit mode is indeed not consistent since the face normal directions are pretty arbitrary. Sometimes it rotates the object by 90 degrees, sometimes its not perfectly aligned etc. Best way is still to do it in object mode